# multipart form data with wso2 esb is it possible?

Tags: wso2, multipartform-data

How to upload multipart form data in wso2 esb without using class mediator. uploading pdf file in wso2 ESB using choose file option in postman

Comment: This can be easily achieved using simple proxy service or API.WSO2 ESB supports multipart/form-data content type messages. Are you facing any issue? What is the version of ESB you are using?

Comment: can you please share your proxy service code or api...i am using 6.4.0 version

Comment: Hi @PriyadarshiniPunjabi
I am aslo having similar use case.can you please help me ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347153/attachment-handling-through-wso2-ei-6-1-1-in-api

Answer (score 0):

In axis2.xml file uncomment `multipart/form-data` if commented,for both message formatter and message builder.